# Using a Label vs using a Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, label

I have a C# Application where I am using Serial communication with a Microcontroller to Display data on the application. I have used a text box to display the data :

```
  public void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            DataRec = serialPort1.ReadExisting();   
            int.TryParse(DataRec, out myTotal);
            this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText)); 
        }
        catch(NullReferenceException)
        {
          //catching the exception

        }
   }

  public void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBox2.Text = myTotal.ToString();
    }
```

Instead of TextBoxes I have also tried using labels. I get the same result and I didnt see any change in performance. I am using labels because I didnt want the user to think they can edit the values in the textboxes.

I have tried searching for the advantages of one over the other. So far the ones I have seen is :

1. Textboxes need to be set as readonly whereas in labels you dont need to do that.
2. Even when I set the textboxes as read only the Cursor is still visible whereas in Label it isn't.

What are some of the pros and cons in terms of performance, while using either a Label or Textbox?

Is it ok if I use labels ?

Comment: Labels are for text to be displayed (info for the user), TextBox are when you need to get input from your user or you need an edit operation or allow a copy (Ctrl+C) of the text even when you don't want any editing. Of course TextBox are more heavy in terms of system resources but the difference is negligible. In your context, just use labels.

Comment: @Steve Thank you, I will use labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few pro's and con's to both.

### Label

**Pro's:**

- Text is not copy able
- Cursor does not change
- Sets size based on text (if autosize is on, I think its on by default)
- Option to align text to the right (autosize off)

**Con's:**

- Text is not selectable/copy able
- Text might outgrow form/parent with autosize

### TextBox

**Pro's:**

- Text is copy able
- Fixed size (also a con)

**Con's:**

- Does not autosize
- Height not adjustable (does not apply to rich textbox/`multiline = true`)

**My opinion:**
In my opinion you should use a label if the user shouldn't be able to copy the data. The exception to this is if you have just 1 un-editable value and all others are textbox's, then you should just make a readonly textbox.

Comment: thank for the detailed information. 1 up for the property explanation. I will use the Label. I wanted to know whether Labels will slow down the application or will be heavy on resources, but Steve answered that.

Comment: @Adds Steve did indeed answer those details, but as you said you did not notice a change in performance, I thought it would not be of use if I focused on that :)

Comment: I like your detailed answer, I have selected it as the answer.

Comment: @Adds Thanks, glad to be some sort of help.

Answer (score 1):

You have already answered your own question. It seems clear to me that a label is more appropriate in this case. You could argue that later that you may need the extra functionality that the text box provides but you should consider the [YAGNI](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/Yagni.html) principle.

As to pros and cons, the user will probably believe they are able to edit the value in the text box, they wont make that mistake using a label.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm on the performance related issues I would have with labels(If there were any or if someone faced an issue with labels), Thanks